# What is the simplest way to mock a fetch call that is only meant to run in the browser with jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, jestjs, fetch

If I'm testing a function that makes a fetch call, and all the fetch calls I have in the project are only meant to run in the browser. Do I still need to have some package installed on node and import it to be able to mock that fetch call?

A simple scenario like this throws `ReferenceError: fetch is not defined` in the Jest test:

```js
// fetcKey.js

export async function fetchKey() {
    try {

        const key = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/key');
        return (await key.text());
    }
    catch(error){
        throw error;
    }
}

//fetchKey.test.js

import fetchKey from './fetchKey'

test('Checks fetchKey return', () => {

    expect(fetchKey()).not.toThrow();

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use [`node-fetch`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch):

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

(Note it's an ECMAScript Module and cannot be imported with `require`, as mentioned in their documentation).

Comment: thanks mate, is there a way around this without node-fetch? reason is, I'm not actually making any fetch calls from the backend. Maybe this sounds stupid but is there a way to sort of create a global "fake" fetch function that's local to the project?

Comment: I don't think so, but you could just make one that returns a super simple promise and go with that. (just so your `await` procs).